# Where does the performance boost of map or list comprehension implementations over calling a function over a loop come from?

Tags: python, algorithm, performance, functional-programming

I understand that you could be more efficient with memory in the implementation of map than in how you might do it over a loop. However, I see that using a map function over calling a function iterating over a loop has a speed boost as well.

Is this coming from some optimization in where to store the memory? One example of what I mean by this is placement of memory done in such a way that it is contiguous. Also I can see that if the operations were being in run in parallel then there would also be a speed boost, but I don't think this is the case. Examples from any known optimizations for map implementations from any language/package are very welcome!

-- Edit: I feel as if the example I had previously did not illustrate my question very well.

MAY NOT BE COMPLETELY FAIR COMPARISON.
For example, I test the a loop implementation, list comprehension, and the map function. Would you have any ideas of what would make one faster than the other? NOT NECESSARILY PYTHON; this is more a question about implementation of more efficient algorithms for applying a function over an iterable object. A valid answer might be that "typically for every map/list comprehension style of code, you would be able to make a loop implementation faster than that". Or for some case, the list comprehension is faster, but this relates to the implementation details and that is what I am interested in.

```
import time
import numpy as np


def square2(x):
return x*x


def main():
    foobar = np.linspace(1, 300, 300)

    start_time = time.time()
    res = [0] * len(foobar)
    for i, foo in enumerate(foobar):
        res[i] = square2(foo)
    print("{} {} runtime seconds {}".format("-"*8, time.time()-start_time, "-"*8))

    res = [0] * len(foobar)
    start_time = time.time()
    res = [square2(foo) for foo in foobar]
    print("{} {} runtime seconds {}".format("-"*8, time.time()-start_time, "-"*8))

    start_time = time.time()
    res = list(map(square2, foobar))
    print("{} {} runtime seconds {}".format("-"*8, time.time()-start_time, "-"*8))
```

The output is:

```
-------- 6.175041198730469e-05 runtime seconds --------
-------- 5.984306335449219e-05 runtime seconds --------
-------- 5.316734313964844e-05 runtime seconds --------
```

Comment: Why do you think its map?  In one case you extend 1 at a time, in the other you create one list.

Comment: But your example is only applicable to Python. Calling a function over and over again in a loop is particularly expensive in Python, because there is a lot of overhead to function calls, but will be cheap in a language like Java.

Comment: On my system the list comprehension is always fastest.  I tried it over several different sizes, up to 1M.

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga oh so do you mean in a language like Java, the JIT might inline the function? So you are saying that in a language like python, what might be going on in map/list comprehension implementation is they keep a direct pointer to a function, but in a regular loop it will always have to go through some process of retrieving the function at each loop?

Comment: @itzjustricky yep. Lemme show you something more concretely in Python.

Comment: @stark yes, comprehesions are usually the fastest way to go.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So, the issue with function-calls in loops, in a dynamic language like Python, is that the interpreter has to evalute the refernces each time, and that is costly, especially for global variables. However, notice what happens when you make things local:

```
import time
def square(x):
    return x*x

def test_loop(x):
    res = []
    for i in x:
        res.append(square(i))
    return res


def test_map(x):
    return  list(map(square,x))

def test_map_local(x, square=square):
    return  list(map(square,x))


def test_loop_local(x, square=square):
    res = []
    for i in x:
        res.append(square(i))
    return res

def test_loop_local_local(x, square=square):
    res = []
    append = res.append
    for i in x:
        append(square(i))
    return res

def test_comprehension(x):
    return [square(i) for i in x]

def test_comprehension_local(x, square=square):
    return [square(i) for i in x]

x = range(1,10000000)

start = time.time()
test_loop(x)
stop = time.time()
print("Loop:", stop - start,"seconds")

start = time.time()
test_loop_local(x)
stop = time.time()
print("Loop-local:", stop - start, "seconds")

start = time.time()
test_loop_local_local(x)
stop = time.time()
print("Loop-local-local:", stop - start, "seconds")

start = time.time()
test_map(x)
stop = time.time()
print("Map:", stop - start, "seconds")

start = time.time()
test_map_local(x)
stop = time.time()
print("Map-local:", stop - start, "seconds")

start = time.time()
test_comprehension(x)
stop = time.time()
print("Comprehesion:", stop - start, "seconds")

start = time.time()
test_comprehension_local(x)
stop = time.time()
print("Comprehesion-local:", stop - start, "seconds")
```

Results:

```
Loop: 3.9749317169189453 seconds
Loop-local: 3.686530828475952 seconds
Loop-local-local: 3.006138563156128 seconds
Map: 3.1068732738494873 seconds
Map-local: 3.1318843364715576 seconds
Comprehesion: 2.973804235458374 seconds
Comprehesion-local: 2.7370445728302 seconds
```

So, making the function look-up in map local doesn't really help, as I would expect because map does a single look-up at the beginning. What really surprised me is that there seems to be a non-negligible difference between a comprehension and a comprehension with the function made local. Not sure if this is just noise, however.

Comment: @itzjustricky Also, read this: https://www.python.org/doc/essays/list2str/

Answer (score 0):

The difference is due to append, not map.  Try this:

```
res = []
res = [square2(foo) for foo in foobar]
```

Comment: I don't think is a fair comparison either since for the generator, I don't even think it has done the computation yet over the other items in foobar ...

Comment: I changed to an array and you can see that the times are now close to equal.

Comment: @stark huh? `res.append` modifies an existing list.

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga Yes.  It extends it by 1 each time through the loop.  Whereas the list comprehension only creates the list once.

Comment: @stark yes, but it's the same list. Only one list is created in the for-loop example.

Comment: and if I paiint over the Mona Lisa its still the Mona Lisa because all I did was append to it.

Comment: Look, we are not talking about the ship of Theseus here. I simply mean that by object identity, they are the same. Under the hood, a list comprehension builds a list using the same process. Python lists are dynamic arrays. The append operation works with the same block of memory, and it's an amortized constant time operation. It isn't like an immutable data structure, which needs to rebuild the list each time, only when resizing. That is what I've understood. If I am mistaken, by all means let me know.