# Print a nested lists line by line without for loop

Tags: python, list, python-3.x, nested

I can print nested lists line by line by using for loop and " ".join() mapping each int in the nested list to a str with map().

Example:

```
>>> ys = [[1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6], [7, 8, 9, 10]]
>>> for xs in ys:
...     print(" ".join(map(str, xs)))
... 
1 2 3
4 5 6
7 8 9 10
```

But I am trying to figure out how to do this again without for loops that can support arbitrary lengths of inner lists. Any suggestions?

Comment: Is there any particular reason you're avoiding a for loop?

Comment: Not really... I just wanted to practice solving a problem with different approaches.

Comment: So, are you saying that the lists within lists could go deeper? Like you could have a list within a list within a list?

Comment: I didn't think of that case and that could get messy and I don't know how I would enter each row.. so for the sake of practice I'll just assume that its just a list within a list.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since the depth is known and fixed, you can nest 2 `map` statements in a one-liner, using `lambda` to avoid comprehension (which would involve a `for` loop)

```
ys = [[1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6], [7, 8, 9, 10]]
print("\n".join(map(lambda xs : " ".join(map(str, xs)),ys)))
```

no `for` loop, at least none visible.

From a performance point of view, `map` performs a loop but problably compiled, so it is faster. On the other hand, `join` needs to know the size of the input so a `list` is created out of the iterable anyway, and `join` + *list* comprehension is then faster (not in Python 2 where `map` returns a `list`). In a word: use `timeit` to determine the fastest variant with your context.

Comment: Thanks! That would make sense to use 2 map statements. I didn't think of that method!

Comment: The performance considerations when thinking about `map` vs for-loop or `map` vs `comprehension` are not as straight-forward. See http://stackoverflow.com/a/39046254/5014455 There is also the added complication that built-in functions generally are mapped faster using `map`, compared to an equivalent list comprehension, but user-defined functions show the opposite pattern (comprehensions map faster than `map`).

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga `timeit` will be the only judge :)

Answer (score 1):

```
ys = [[1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6], [7, 8, 9, 10]]
print "\n".join( [" ".join(map(str,subList)) for subList in ys] )
```

Code Explained:

`[" ".join(map(str,subList)) for subList in ys]`

This created a list of string with each value of each list combined with a space.

`["1 2 3", "4 5 6", "7 8 9 10"]`

`"\n".join()` is pretty self explantory after that.

EDIT:

Updated to use `lambda` instead of `for`.

```
ys = [[1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6], [7, 8, 9, 10]]
print "\n".join( map(lambda x: " ".join(map(str,x)),ys) )
```

Comment: Yeah that would make sense except for the for. Thanks though! Interesting solution.

Comment: @pewnienewbie, I updated this to use `lambda` instead of `for`. Not sure if this will be okay.

Comment: @Michael, yeah that would work! That's actually what Jean-Francois did :)

Comment: @Michael: Quick question, why does "\n"join() print with a new space when print is written before it and if there wasn't a print it would of just been '1 2 3\n4 5 6\n7 8 9 10'. Does print take \n as an enter?

Answer (score 1):

As a recursive function for any length/depth of lists:

```
def recursive_print_list(param):
    while len(param) > 0:
        if isinstance(param[0], list):
            recursive_print_list(param[0])
            print("")
            param = param[1:]
        else:
            print(param[0], '', end='')
            param = param[1:]
```

Worth noting the other two answers won't work for depth > 2. This will. It also relies on `print()`s implicit conversion to string, and will therefore work on any mixed input so long as you can `print(element)` all elements.

---

Original Answer:

```
xs = ys[:]  # copy the original list, as this method is destructive
while True:
    try:
        print " ".join(map(str, xs[0]))
        xs = xs[1:]
    except IndexError:
        break
```

will work for arbitrary nested lists of ints.

You could use the same method to avoid the map call as well:
Python 3:

```
xs = ys[:]
while True:
    if len(xs) == 0:
        break
    subl = xs[0][:]
    while True:
        try:
            print(subl[0], ' ', sep='', end='')
            subl = subl[1:]
        except IndexError:
            print("")
            break
    xs = xs[1:]
```

Python 2.7:

```
xs = ys[:]
while True:
    if len(xs) == 0:
        break
    subl = xs[0][:]
    while True:
        try:
            print subl[0],
            subl = subl[1:]
        except IndexError:
            print ""
            break
    xs = xs[1:]
```