# Faster alternative to using the `map` function

Tags: python, arrays, python-3.x, numpy, dictionary

I have a function `f`, for exapmle:

```
def f(x):
    return x**2
```

and want to obtain an array consisting of `f` evaluated over an interval, for example the unit interval (0,1). We ca do this as follows:

```
import numpy as np
X = np.arange(0,1,0.01)
arr = np.array(list(map(f, X)))
```

However, this last line is very time consuming when the function is complicated (in my case it involves some integrals). Is there a way to do this faster? I am happy to have a non-elegant solution - the focus is on speed.

Comment: I wouldn't be worried about the `map()` overhead if `X` is not huge in length. Spend time optimizing your `f()`.

Comment: It's not an answer to your question, but building a list just to make an array is pretty inefficient. You can use [`fromiter()`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.fromiter.html) to avoid doing that. You need to know the length, but given it's a map operation, you know that'll be the same as the array you are mapping over. If you want speed with Numpy, however, you'll want to use numpy operations - maps inherantly mean python-side loops and operations, which will be slower.

Comment: @zwer Agreed. You can get some speed-up using a list-comprehension, but it won't significantly alter the overall runtime. Check out some experiments I did to answer [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39045396/where-does-the-performance-boost-of-map-or-list-comprehension-implementations-ov/39046254#39046254)

Comment: @GarethLatty Actually, I think if you just refactor the code into a for-loop that takes an `np.empty` array and assigns by index the right values it will be faster than `fromiter`, not sure though. `fromiter` is generally slow, `numpy` arrays are pretty much C arrays and building it up piecemeal is not efficient at all. I wouldn't be surprised if under the hood, `fromiter` consumes the iterator into a list anyeway...

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga The docs say: ['Specify count to improve performance. It allows fromiter to pre-allocate the output array, instead of resizing it on demand.'](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.fromiter.html) - sounds like it'll do the optimal thing in that case - at least in comparison to making a list or multiple resizes.

Comment: @GarethLatty good catch.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If `f` is so complicated that it can't be expressed in terms of compiled array operations, and can only take scalars, I have found that `frompyfunc` gives the best performance (about 2x compared to an explicit loop)

```
In [76]: def f(x):
    ...:     return x**2
    ...: 

In [77]: foo = np.frompyfunc(f,1,1)

In [78]: foo(np.arange(4))
Out[78]: array([0, 1, 4, 9], dtype=object)

In [79]: foo(np.arange(4)).astype(int)
Out[79]: array([0, 1, 4, 9])
```

It returns dtype object, so needs an `astype`.  `np.vectorize` uses this as well, but is a bit slower.  Both generalize to various shapes of input array(s).

For a 1d result `fromiter` works with `map` (without the `list`) part:

```
In [84]: np.fromiter((f(x) for x in range(4)),int)
Out[84]: array([0, 1, 4, 9])

In [86]: np.fromiter(map(f, range(4)),int)
Out[86]: array([0, 1, 4, 9])
```

You'll have to do your own timings in a realistic case.

Answer (score 4):

You could use list comprehension to slightly decrease runtime.

```
arr = [f(x) for x in range(0, 5)] # range is the interval
```

This should work. It will only slightly decrease runtime though. You shouldn't be worried about runtime unless you use very large numbers with `map()`.

Answer (score 1):

Use operations that operate on entire arrays. For example, with a function that just squares the input (slightly corrected from your example):

```
def f(x):
    return x**2
```

then you'd just do

```
arr = f(X)
```

because NumPy defines operators like `**` to operate on entire arrays at once.

Your real function might not be quite as straightforward. You say there are integrals involved; to make whole-array operations work with that, you might have to pass arguments differently or change what you're using to compute the integrals. In general, though, whole-array operations will vastly outperform anything that needs to call Python-level code in a loop.

Answer (score 1):

You could try `numpy.vectorize`. It's very good way to apply function to list or array

```
import numpy as np

def foo(x):
    return x**2

foo = np.vectorize(foo)
arr = np.arange(10)

In [1]: foo(arr)                                                                                    
Out[1]: array([ 0,  1,  4,  9, 16, 25, 36, 49, 64, 81])
```