# Fastest way to iterate through loops in various scenarios

Tags: python, arrays, performance, python-2.7, numpy

After extensive profiling of our source code base, we found out that all performance issues are caused while we are looping over some huge lists.

The code passages that are causing the issues could be identified as follows:

```
#ISSUE 1
myList = [i for j, i in enumerate(myList) if j not in anotherList]

#ISSUE 2
TargetIndex = next((myList.index(n) for n in myList if n > someBoundary), len(myList))

#ISSUE 3
def myFunction():
    for i in myList:
        if abs(i) > someLimit:
            return 0
    return 1

#ISSUE 4
for n,i in enumerate(myList):
    if abs(i) < someLimit:
        myList[n] = 0
```

I am quite sure that some `numpy` experts could write down four one-liners that would lead to a great performance boost of our application. But perhaps there may even be a better way for those looping operations than `numpy` which I am not aware of.

Any suggestions on the topic are highly appreciated.

Comment: These are all working on lists.  Why the numpy question? If they were arrays we might suggest faster compiled operations.  But for that we need to know things like shape and dtype.

Comment: Hi. The data type of all list elements is always float and the list is flat (no list of lists).

Comment: For more of a numpy context look at http://stackoverflow.com/q/42356625

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First issue: make a lookup in a `set` instead of a `list`

```
anotherSet = set(anotherList)
myList = [i for j, i in enumerate(myList) if j not in anotherSet]
```

Second issue: why computing `index` of `n` when you already iterating on the list? Use `enumerate`

```
TargetIndex = next((i for i,n in enumerate(myList) if n > someBoundary), len(myList))
```

For issues 3 & 4, there's not much you can do but precompute the list of absolute values so you don't perform it twice on the same list.

```
abs_vals = [abs(n) for n in myList]
```

so for instance the 4th snippet becomes:

```
for index,av in enumerate(abs_vals):
    if av < someLimit:
        myList[index] = 0
```

Comment: Wow. THAT was fast. Thanks a lot. I will try it out.

Comment: Worked great. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

As a warning, you'll have to change a lot more than these if you want to keep your data as numpy arrays, but this is how you fix the issues you have.

```
import numpy as np

myArr=np.array(myList)

#1
myArr = myArr[np.in1d(np.arange(myArr.size), anotherList, invert = True)]

#2
TargetIndex = next(np.nonzero(myArr > someBoundary)[0].flat, myArr.size)

#3
def myFunction():
    return (np.abs(myArr) <= someLimit).astype(int)

#4
np.where(np.abs(myArr) < someLimit, 0, myArr)
```