# Does It affect the memory consumption in program

Tags: python, memory-management

```
return sum(x for x in list)
vs 
for x in list:
   sum+=x
return sum
```

does 1st the statement execute faster and the memory used by both the programs is same or not.
I am not able to find this answer specifically/

Comment: What about `sum(list)`?

Comment: @ScottHunter yes it can be but it can be a sum of odd indices or even. My concern is about the difference in single liner vs stepwise code .

Comment: @OsourceAll Thanks. One more Follow up question does the first program contains copy of variable sum or not

Comment: `sum` isn't a variable.

Comment: @ScottHunter oh sorry i meant in a return statement if there is something like-> return sum=4+5 where I just use the variable in return statement

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39045396/where-does-the-performance-boost-of-map-or-list-comprehension-implementations-ov

Comment: @tripleee thanks for the link but still I didn't get the answer to my last question in the comment that I asked.

Comment: " My concern is about the difference in single liner vs stepwise code" that is irrelevant when it comes to performance. Both pieces of code here have the same time/space complexity.. Have you tried *profiling* your code to find out which one is faster, if any?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is nearly no difference for most cases. If you are really memory constrained, use `sum` because it is optimised (but Python and native lists should be a bigger concern to you).